# Jquery Cycle plugin: multiple pager counter with multiple slideshow on one page

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I have a page counter -with (1/9) system- for multiple slideshow on one page.
My problem is: 
when I click on one slideshow
it doesn't only affect the pages-counter of this one 
but all the pages-counter of the different slideshows present on that page...

If somebody have a solution to solve my problem I would be grateful.

**Here my JQuery code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slidecontein .slideshow').each(function(){
                $(this).cycle({
                    speed:1, 
                    timeout: 0,
                    next: $('.slideright', $(this).parent()),
                    prev: $('.slideleft', $(this).parent()),
                    after: function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
                        var caption = (opts.currSlide + 1) + ' / ' + opts.slideCount;
                        $('.counter').html(caption);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**here my html code sample**

```
<div class="slidecontein"> 
 <div class="slideleft"> </div>
 <div class="slideright"> </div>

 <div class="slideshow"> 
 <div class="slide1">
 <img src="../imgs/01.jpg">
 </div>

  <div class="slide2">
 <img src="../imgs/02.jpg"> 
 </div>

 <div class="slide3">
 <img src="../imgs/03.jpg">
 </div>

    </div> <!-- END slideshow -->

       <div id="counter"></div>     <!-- my pages-counter -->

</div><!-- END slidecontein -->


<div class="slidecontein"> 
 <div class="slideleft"> </div>
 <div class="slideright"> </div>

 <div class="slideshow"> 

<div class="slide1">
 <img src="../imgs/10.jpg">
 </div>

  <div class="slide2">
 <img src="../imgs/11.jpg"> 
 </div>


 </div> <!-- END slideshow -->
 <div id="counter"></div>            <!-- my page counter -->
 </div><!-- END slidecontein -->
```

I've also tried this:

```
var ss=$(this).closest('.slidecontein')
```

but still not working (it's breaking the slideshow)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the .each() method on the selector '.slidecontein .slideshow' which is not unique, ensuring that this will match multiple elements.  Basically, your .cycle() method code is controlling more than one slideshow at a time.

You'd be better off assigning an ID to each slideshow container and using the .cycle() method on each one individually.  That way they are all will be independently controlled.